# as.Date showing character string in unambiguous format even when strptime specified R

Tags: r, date

I have this date column of form:

```
20160812
20160813
```

Basically YYYYMMDD.

I converted it to a date using strptime and as.Date

```
weather_dataset$DATE = as.Date(weather_dataset$DATE,"%Y%m%d")
```

But I get

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Huh? I've clearly specified the format to use, but its still throwing me this error for some reason. Would appreciate help! :)

Thank you!

Comment: or [R read dates in format yyyymmdd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116388/r-read-dates-in-format-yyyymmdd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data has to be a character. So use this workaround:

```
weather_dataset$DATE <- as.Date(as.character(weather_dataset$DATE),"%Y%m%d")
```

Another possibility is the library(lubridate):

```
weather_dataset$DATE <- lubridate::ymd(weather_dataset$DATE)
```

Comment: You're amazing, thanks! Will mark as correct once the min time limit allows me to

Answer (score 2):

```
library(anytime)

anydate(20160812)
```