# R Code read Google Sheet specific rows based on the cell value

Tags: r, google-sheets

I am reading a GSheet using R Code.

```
temp <- read_sheet(url, sheet = "DATA", range = cell_cols("A:N"), col_types = 'c')
```

The **temp** variable is a list with a structure like follows:

**Col1 Col2 .. Date**

I want only get rows where a value in the **Date column** equals to the current date. Or even before creating temp variable read only rows with the current date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since read_sheet already return a tibble table, you can simply apply a filter to the dataframe for rows where the Date is equals the current date (`Sys.Date()`), like this:

```
temp <- read_sheet(url, sheet = "DATA", range = cell_cols("A:N"), col_types = 'c')
        %>% dplyr::filter(Date == Sys.Date())
```

This assumes your Date columns is formated YYYY-MM-DD, if is not, you can use base::format function to format it in a way it matches your data.

Comment: Hi Julio, I am getting this error 
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
i Input `..1` is `"Date" == Sys.Date()`.

Comment: @JohnDilinjer do you mind sharing some information about your data? maybe it has to do with the way your Date column is formated, could be its type is already Date instead of string. 
try doing
```%>% dplyr::filter(Date ==  lubridate::ymd(Sys.Date()))``` instead

Comment: also: see this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/40528223/10998856

Comment: it worked well with lubridate::ymd(Sys.Date())). It was a date type in the GSheet. Thank you very much!

Comment: aslo is it possible to read the rows within an interval i.e. 7 days interval. I am trying to use something like interval(lubridate::ymd(Sys.Date() - 7), lubridate::ymd(Sys.Date())) But it gives an error Input `..1` must be a logical vector, not a Interval.
i Input `..1` is `interval(lubridate::ymd(Sys.Date() - 7), lubridate::ymd(Sys.Date()))`.

Comment: you could use two filters
```%>% dplyr::filter(Date >=  lubridate::ymd(Sys.Date() - 7))
%>% dplyr::filter(Date <=  lubridate::ymd(Sys.Date()))```